# Remove Node in XML based on SubNode Value

Tags: xml, batch-file

Currently, I have a [script](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8450004#file-replace-courses-bat) that does the following:

1. Looks in a specific folder
2. Unzips all *.zip files
3. Reads a specific [CSV file](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8450004#file-courses-csv) that has four columns (oldid,oldname,newid,newname)
4. Finds all *.xml files recursively in the folder ([sample.xml](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8450004#file-sample-xml))
5. Cycles through *.xml files, creates copy (an original bak & potential modified bak)
6. Replaces oldid,oldname with newid,newname
7. If modified, writes to XML, deleting original file, moving bak to original.

My issue is this. For items with no replacement (e.g., [line 3 of csv](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8450004#file-courses-csv-L3)), I need to delete the entire node.

So in my XML, I have this:

```
<choice id="8" isActive="yes">
    <name><![CDATA[<font color='#0000FF' ><u>Mentoring Tools</u> </font>]]></name>
    <url><![CDATA[http://olc.inside.domain.com/olc/apps/pro/DeepLinking/LoadAsset.cfm?coursename=mgmt_10_a03_bs_enus]]></url>
</choice>
```

When I walk through this, I will touch them line by line in my [current loop](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8450004#file-replace-courses-bat-L72-L83). So my question is this, is there a way to set a delimiter to read in order to replace string or remove said node? Or, since replacing works, use the replacement tool to write an empty line?

So,

```
<choice id="8" isActive="yes">
    <name><![CDATA[<font color='#0000FF' ><u>Mentoring Tools</u> </font>]]></name>
    <url><![CDATA[http://olc.inside.domain.com/olc/apps/pro/DeepLinking/LoadAsset.cfm?coursename=mgmt_10_a03_bs_enus]]></url>
</choice>
```

becomes

```
<choice id="8" isActive="yes">
</choice>
```

If this works, then use another batch to remove any empty `<choice>` nodes?

So going with this later line of thinking, why does this change `>> "%BAKFILE%" echo.!LINE!` => `if not "%~3"=="" >> "%BAKFILE%" echo.!LINE!` not work?

[Related Question #21153875](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8450004#file-replace-courses-bat).

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me. Your question is an annoying one. In first place, you give too much information that is unrelated to the problem. However, when you describe your question, you are not clear enough: "*is there a way to set a delimiter to read in order to replace string or remove said node?*".

If this is the related loop:

```
REM Walk through XML Lines
for /F "delims=" %%U in (%~1) do (
    set LINE=%%U
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    if not "!LINE!" == "!LINE:%~2=!" (
        set LINE=!LINE:%~2=%~3!
        set modified=!string:%~2=%~3!

    )
    >> "%BAKFILE%" echo.!LINE!
    endlocal
)
```

... and this is the input data:

```
<choice id="8" isActive="yes">
    <name><![CDATA[<font color='#0000FF' ><u>Mentoring Tools</u> </font>]]></name>
    <url><![CDATA[http://olc.inside.domain.com/olc/apps/pro/DeepLinking/LoadAsset.cfm?coursename=mgmt_10_a03_bs_enus]]></url>
</choice>
```

... then I don't understand in which cases the output is (or should be, or you want to be) this:

```
<choice id="8" isActive="yes">
</choice>
```

Anyway, I still don't understand how all this stuff is related to your *real* problem.

If you real question is: "How to cancel the output of the entire empty `<choice...> </choice>` nodes when...", then I suggest you to complete the "..." part in a very clear way so we know what is the problem to solve.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. That is my problem. I have an empty node `<choice id="8" isActive="yes"></choice>` What I need is the empty node to be removed entirely if that is the resulting output.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (courses.csv) do (
set "_oID=%%a"
set "_oName=%%b"
set "nID=%%c"
set "nName=%%d"
call :newprocessLine
PAUSE
)
GOTO :eof

:newprocessLine
:: Simulate xml-file-located-by-for/r
SET "sourcefile=q21169335.txt"
SET "destfile=q21169335.txt.new"
DEL %destfile% 2>nul

CALL :zap $
SET "choicenode="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (%sourcefile%) DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 REM line below delims=redirectors TAB space
 FOR /f "delims=<>   " %%t IN ("%%a") DO SET "tag=%%t"
 CALL :rep
)

FC %sourcefile% %destfile%

GOTO :eof

:: with each line, buffer if in choice node else output
:rep
IF "%tag%"=="choice" SET choicenode=Y&SET "targetnode="
IF DEFINED choicenode (CALL :buffer) ELSE (CALL :out line)
IF "%tag%"=="/choice" GOTO eciohctag
GOTO :eof

:: save and flag whether target
:buffer
SET /a count$+=1
SET "$%count$%=%line%"
CALL SET "newline=%%line:%_oID%=%%"
IF NOT "%line%"=="%newline%" SET targetnode=Y
GOTO :eof

:: Process any changes required
:: If no new ID and no new Name, eliminate node
:eciohctag
IF NOT DEFINED targetnode GOTO putbuffer
IF NOT DEFINED nID IF NOT DEFINED nName GOTO noput
FOR /l %%z IN (1,1,%count$%) DO (
 CALL SET "$%%z=%%$%%z:%_oID%=%nID%%%"
 CALL SET "$%%z=%%$%%z:%_oName%=%nName%%%"
)
:putbuffer
FOR /l %%z IN (1,1,%count$%) DO (CALL :out $%%z)

:noput
CALL :zap $
SET "choicenode="
GOTO :eof

:: remove all envvars starting %1
:zap
FOR /f "delims==" %%z IN ('set %1 2^>nul') DO SET "%%z="
SET /a count%1=0
GOTO :eof

:out
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%x IN ('set %1') DO >>%destfile% ECHO(%%y
GOTO :eof
```

I suggest you sort out your file-copying/backup generation scheme. Seems to me you're copying files and immediately deleting them...

With that in mind, I've generated this version. Essentially, it processes the same file, `q21169335.txt` (a copy of your `.XML` example) and generates a new file `q21169335.txt.new` three times, stopping after a `FC` to show differences. The three times are once for each line of `courses.csv` to show the individual changes made by each iteration.

Essentially, the approach is to detect the tag, buffer any lines between `choice` and `/choice` and if the node buffered contains the old-id string then process that node, replacing the old data with new.

If the new data has neither new name nor new ID, then the node is skipped.

---

Result when run against data in file posted to github:

```
Comparing files q21169335.xml and Q21169335.XML.NEW
***** q21169335.xml
<choice id="9" isActive="yes">
<name><![CDATA[<font color='#0000FF' ><u>Mentoring Effectively</u> </font>]]></name>
<url><![CDATA[http://olc.inside.domain.com/olc/apps/pro/DeepLinking/LoadAsset.cfm?coursename=mgmt_10_a01_bs_enus]]></url>
</choice>
***** Q21169335.XML.NEW
<choice id="9" isActive="yes">
<name><![CDATA[<font color='#0000FF' ><u>Essential Mentoring Techniques</u> </font>]]></name>
<url><![CDATA[http://olc.inside.domain.com/olc/apps/pro/DeepLinking/LoadAsset.cfm?coursename=mgmt_39_a01_bs_enus]]></url>
</choice>
*****

Press any key to continue . . . 
Comparing files q21169335.xml and Q21169335.XML.NEW
***** q21169335.xml
<choice id="7" isActive="yes">
<name><![CDATA[<font color='#0000FF' ><u>Mentoring as a Manager</u> </font>]]></name>
<url><![CDATA[http://olc.inside.domain.com/olc/apps/pro/DeepLinking/LoadAsset.cfm?coursename=mgmt_10_a02_bs_enus]]></url>
</choice>
***** Q21169335.XML.NEW
<choice id="7" isActive="yes">
<name><![CDATA[<font color='#0000FF' ><u>Essential Mentoring Techniques</u> </font>]]></name>
<url><![CDATA[http://olc.inside.domain.com/olc/apps/pro/DeepLinking/LoadAsset.cfm?coursename=mgmt_39_a02_bs_enus]]></url>
</choice>
*****

Press any key to continue . . . 
Comparing files q21169335.xml and Q21169335.XML.NEW
***** q21169335.xml
</choice>
<choice id="8" isActive="yes">
<name><![CDATA[<font color='#0000FF' ><u>Mentoring Tools</u> </font>]]></name>
<url><![CDATA[http://olc.inside.domain.com/olc/apps/pro/DeepLinking/LoadAsset.cfm?coursename=mgmt_10_a03_bs_enus]]></url>
</choice>
<choice id="9" isActive="yes">
***** Q21169335.XML.NEW
</choice>
<choice id="9" isActive="yes">
*****

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Fails in what way?

Comment: Using the code replacing .txt with .xml appears to fail? https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/8542453